# Rewrite Long url with custom link

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes

**I have this link :**

```
www.example.com/wp-content/themes/site/modules/library/?pid=55
```

**i want to rewrite it to:**

```
www.example.com/customName/55
```

i try many things into my .htaccess with no success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase  /wp-content/themes/site/modules/library/?pid=$1
RewriteRule https://www.example.com/customName/$1
```

Comment: Mod: i want to rewrite it to:
www.example.com/customName/pid/55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has its own url routing system. You can customise it to shorten your long urls. If you are unable to do so from the settings then use the following rule in your htaccess file  :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^CustomName/([0-9]+)/?$ /wp-content/themes/site/modules/library/?pid=$1 [L,NC]
# other rules
```

Comment: Its not working starkeen, when i access : http://www.example.com/CustomName/55
its give me 404 Page not found :(

Comment: @WPDeveloper Put this at the top of your htaccess  before your other RewriteRules.

Comment: how to do redirect to the new url in case the old url accessed ?

Comment: @WPDeveloper To redirect old url to the new one you can use another rule .. add the following right bellow `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: `RewriteCond ℅{THE_REQUEST} /themes/site/modules/library/\?pid=([O-9]+) [NC] RewriteRule ^ /CustomName/℅1? [L,R]`

Comment: nothing happen when i access www.example.com/wp-content/themes/site/modules/library/?pid=55